# How to find the number of unmasked images in a collection at a point in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to know how to count the number of unmasked pixels in a single geometry point i.e. how many images have not been masked at that location.
The following code counts all images, both masked and unmasked at the point of interest, I would like to know the number for each.

```js
//specifies the start and end date
var start_time = ee.Date('2001-01-01');
var end_time = ee.Date('2010-01-01');

//specifies area of interest
var poi = ee.Geometry.Point([1.1370849609375,52.20171539256484]);

//filters landsat 5 collection to date and roi
var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(poi)
.filterDate(start_time, end_time);

//creates a cloud mask
var cloud_func = function(img){ 
  return img.updateMask(img.select(['pixel_qa']).bitwiseAnd(2).neq(0));  
  };  

//applies the mask
var masked_collection = landsat5.map(cloud_func);

//prints the total number of landsat images 
var number_of_landsats = ee.Number(masked_collection.size());
print(number_of_landsats, 'number');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an image counting all unmasked pixels and then use `reduceRegion` to count only the unmasked pixels at your POI.

```js
// creates an image with the number of unmasked pixels
var number_unmasked_pixels = masked_collection.select("B1").count()

// count pixels at poi
var unmasked_pixels_poi = number_unmasked_pixels.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), poi, 30)

print(unmasked_pixels_poi, "unmasked pixels in POI")
```