# Count valid (unmasked) per-pixel observations in MODIS time series collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a quality image that describes the number of valid (unmasked) observations per pixel time series given a MODIS vegetation image collection.

I want to get a sense for how frequently a given location is masked out because of poor quality or cloud cover to use as a metric to qualify analysis results. For example, if during a given season six observations (images) exist, I want to calculate a map layer that is the count of unmasked observations, so that I can exclude results from pixel time series where the number of observations is less than 3, for instance.

This code block produces a MODIS vegetation index image collection for northern hemisphere summer months and uses the quality band to update each image's mask. How can I count the per-pixel number of unmasked observations given this collection?

```js
// Load all MODIS 13Q1 data from a few months in 2018.
var modisVegCol = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
  .filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-07-31');

// Define a function to mask image by quality band.
function qualityMask(img) {
  // Make boolean image where high quality pixels are value 1 and all else 0.
  var mask = img.select('SummaryQA').eq(0);
  // Update the image mask and return it.
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

// Apply quality mask to all images in the collection.
modisVegCol = modisVegCol.map(qualityMask);

// Print the first image.
print(modisVegCol.first());

// Map NDVI mean of the observations.
Map.setCenter(-100.56, 40.97, 4);
Map.addLayer(modisVegCol.select('NDVI').mean(), {min: 0, max: 8000});
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/de852ba5f23dca4a8374d5f4ece8a994?as_external)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write a function that extracts the mask from each image in the collection and returns an image collection composed of a series of image masks.
2. Apply the mask extractor function to the masked MODIS image collection.
3. `.sum()` the extracted mask collection to count the number of unmasked (valid) observations per-pixel time series.
4. Optionally apply `.selfMask()` to the result of summing the extracted mask collection to set pixels with 0 valid observations as masked.

The following code block implements these steps in the provided script.

```js
// Load all MODIS 13Q1 data from a few months in 2018.
var modisVegCol = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
  .filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-07-31');

// Define function to mask image by quality metric. In this case
// the MODIS 'SummaryQA' band.
function qualityMask(img) {
  // Make boolean image where high quality pixels are value 1 and all else 0.
  var mask = img.select('SummaryQA').eq(0);
  // Update the image mask and return it.
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

// Define a function to calculate the number of valid observations for a given
// pixel's time series. Takes a collection of masked images.
function countValidPixels(collection) {
  // For each image in the collection return the mask; returns an image
  // collection.
  return collection.map(function(img) {
    return img.select(0).mask();
  })
  // Sum the masks; this gives valid pixel count.
  .sum()
  // Optionally mask pixels that have 0 observation over the give time series.
  .selfMask();
}

// Apply quality mask to all images in the collection.
modisVegCol = modisVegCol.map(qualityMask);

// Apply the valid pixel counting function.
var validPixelCount = countValidPixels(modisVegCol);

// Check the result.
print(validPixelCount);
Map.addLayer(validPixelCount, {min: 1, max: 6}, 'Valid Pixel Count');
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/63cbc6c466d1fcd69a59722cbec3719f?as_external)

Related questions with answers:

- [Pixel-based calculation of valid observations in Landsat ImageCollection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/308519/68792)
- [How to find the number of unmasked images in a collection at a point in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/282804/68792)